# How to move movies already contained in library to external drive?

Tags: itunes

My iTunes library is located on an external hard drive using the setting Settings > Advanced. Yesterday I bought a movie in the iTunes store without connecting the external hard drive to my computer. Consequently, the movie file is located on my internal hard drive. How can I move it to the external hard drive without any trouble (e.g., loosing rights to watch it "you are not allowed to watch this movie due to DRS" etc.)? For mp3 I locate it on my internal hard drive, copy it to the Desktop, delete it from the iTunes library and import it again. Can I do that for bought movies as well?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the movie within iTunes, plugging you external hard drive and re-downloading it?

Comment: No, because I fear that I have to re-buy it...

Comment: That shouldn't be the case: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2519?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US but I understand you'd like to try some other method first. If you plug the external drive, doesn't iTunes move the movie for you? To force it, you could uncheck and check "Keep iTunes Media folder organized" in Preferences>Advanced Preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an easier solution to this than re-importing, and it works for both movies and songs (and probably everything else, but I haven't had reason to try it on any other media type).

In iTunes, go to the File menu, then select Library, and then Organize Library.  On the resulting dialog, check "Consolidate files".  When you hit OK, any files that have somehow gotten stored in the wrong place will move back to where they belong on your external drive.

After this has completed (it might take a couple of minutes, since I'm assuming that a movie file is big), you can test it out.  Command-click on your movie and select "get info", and then look at its file location on the General tab.  Its file location should show that it's on the external hard drive.  Then you can try to play it.  If it plays successfully, you can then delete it from your internal hard drive.